# List box to allow user typed value

Tags: javascript, gwt, listbox

In `GWT`,how to have a `ListBox` which user can select drop down values as well as he can type hardcoded value in the list box?

NOTE:I should not use any smartgwt,ot ext-gwt in this case.

Comment: Do you mean an autocomplete function? Or adding options dynamically to an select?

Answer (score 1):

You can create this kind of `widget` combining the `TextBox` and the `ListBox`. What i would suggest is place a `TextBox` on a `Panel` and append a `ListBox` inline to it. Reduce the width of the `ListBox` using so that only its dropdown button is visible. Now on selecting a dropdown value call the `TextBox` `setText()`, and where ever you need the value to be selected always use the `TextBox` value.

Sample Code :

Ui-binder

```
<g:HorizontalPanel>
<g:TextBox ui:field="textBox"/>
<g:ListBox ui:field="list" addStyleNames="demo-ListBox"/>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Css :

```
.demo-ListBox {
    width: 20px;
}
```

Java

```
String text = list.getValue(list.getSelectedIndex());
textBox.setText(text);

// use the textBox.getText() always to get the value for the widget
//Also you can later compare the value of textBox and add it to the ListBox if needed via calling the list.addItem(text)
```

End Result :

[image]

Comment: how to append a listbox to textbox?Can u guide me?

Comment: it would be great if you can write up a sample program and show.Unfortunately,when i tried to exercise a sample UIBinder program from google,everytime @UiField is showing 'syntax error on token ínvalid character'delete this token '.....not sure how to sort it out...please help me

Comment: also,please point out if it is available in smartgwt and tutorial link.

Comment: How to exercise a UI binder?Examples in internet are complex...can you guide me?

Comment: @sskumar86 if you are using eclipse it provides default template for creation of a ui binder just say new > uibinder. i havent created ever manually as there is boiler plate code involved that the template fills in...check this http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Widget_World

Comment: yes.I tried and am sucessful to some extent.From the exampel u had shown,how is it possible to shrink the size of listbox(shown down arrow symbol to denote drodown) and merge it with textbox?As of now,list box is too shrinken if i set size as '0%,0%'.Also,  guide me how to make th end user feel like this combination is a comboboxitem ?As of now,look and feel is not implying that...

Comment: you need to play with the css to achieve this. i am not too sure how i can explain all this but check this how to do css , the end result you should be able to achieve by modifying css values for listbox . you can create the ui binder, and once done you can reuse it as a widget by simply using an instance of that ui binder again. check this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_uibinder.htm . also size 0% is of no use width should be reduced

Comment: I tried suggestionbox and my architect approved it.Thanks a ton Onkar.